# Drawing polyline on mapview does not show

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview, polyline

I am trying to connect my pins using `MKPolyline` on my `MKMapView`.
It gives no errors, but the line does not show up on my map.

I have tried everything almost but still can't get it to work.

**[NEW]**

I have tried now commenting the rest out. I also moved everything into the same controller. The child only sends a NSMutableArray with CLLocations to its parent. I have also thought that it might be drawing on a different MKMapView than the one showing on the screen. But it seem not, because I draw pins and a TileOverlay on the same MKMapView with success.

I tried this with no success:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"Drawing overlay");
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        NSLog(@"Drawing routeLine");
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            NSLog(@"Drawing routeLineView");
            NSLog(@"Point Count: %d",self.routeLine.pointCount);
            /*MKMapPoint *tmp = self.routeLine.points;
            for(int i = 0; i < self.routeLine.pointCount;i++)
                NSLog(@"Points: %d\t%@",i, tmp[i]);*/ // Can't find way to output points
            self.routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine] autorelease];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;
            NSLog(@"After setting line specs");
        }
        return self.routeLineView;
        NSLog(@"Not supposed to be called");
    }
    /*TileOverlayView *view = [[TileOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    view.tileAlpha = 0.6;
    return [view autorelease];*/
    return nil;
}
```

This outputs:

> Drawing overlay
>   Drawing routeLine
>   Drawing routeLineView
>   Point Count: 2
>   After setting line specs

---

**[Initial Question]**

I will post my code in reverse of how stuff happens:

**mapView:viewForOverlay:**

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"Drawing overlay");
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
         NSLog(@"Drawing routeLine");
         if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            NSLog(@"Drawing routeLineView");
            self.routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine] autorelease];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;
        }
        return self.routeLineView;
    }
    //Not part of the Question
    TileOverlayView *view = [[TileOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    view.tileAlpha = 0.6;
    return [view autorelease];
}
```

This outputs all to the console:

> Drawing overlay
>   Drawing routeLine
>   Drawing routeLineView

**Adding the line**

```
-(void)addRouteLine:(MKPolyline *)route
{
    self.routeLine = route;
    NSLog(@"addRouteLine"); //Successfully prints in console
    [myMapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
}
```

**Creating the line**
*This happens in a child modal viewcontroller*

```
-(void)loadRoute
{
    // while we create the route points, we will also be calculating the bounding box of our route
    // so we can easily zoom in on it.
    MKMapPoint northEastPoint;
    MKMapPoint southWestPoint;
    // create a c array of points.
    MKMapPoint *pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * waypoints.count);
    MKPolyline *polyLine;
    for(int idx = 0; idx < waypoints.count; idx++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = ((CLLocation *)[waypoints objectAtIndex:idx]).coordinate;

        MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);
        // if it is the first point, just use them, since we have nothing to compare to yet.
        if (idx == 0)
        {
            northEastPoint = point;
            southWestPoint = point;
        }
        else
        {
            if (point.x > northEastPoint.x)
                northEastPoint.x = point.x;
            if(point.y > northEastPoint.y)
                northEastPoint.y = point.y;
            if (point.x < southWestPoint.x)
                southWestPoint.x = point.x;
            if (point.y < southWestPoint.y)
                southWestPoint.y = point.y;
        }

        NSLog(@"Routing Waypoint:\t%f\t%f\t%.02f\t%.02f", point.x, point.y, coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
        pointArr[idx] = point;
    }

    // create the polyline based on the array of points.
    polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:(waypoints.count)];
    if([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
        [(FirstViewController*)self.presentingViewController addRouteLine:polyLine];

    free(pointArr);
}
```

This outputs the data correctly. I currently have two "Routing Waypoints". My output was:

> Routing Waypoint: 145449142.044444    161268376.039062    -34.07  15.06
>   Routing Waypoint: 142917646.563556    157564926.760068    -29.86  11.67

This clearly indicates that the two points are valid points with actual coordinates etc.

---

So it creates the polyline with valid coordinates. Calls the method to draw that polyline. Then it also gets to the point where it adds the polyline as a view.

Why wouldn't this show on the map?
Please help!

Comment: The code looks ok.  Those coordinates are in the Atlantic Ocean off the west coast of South Africa.  Is this where you are expecting them?

Comment: Haha, yes it is. I placed them there so that I don't have to zoom in too much to find them and also on blue, to easily spot the line - the missing one.

Comment: A few things to try: In viewForOverlay, comment/remove the TileOverlayView code and replace with "return nil".  In viewForOverlay, after the "Drawing routeLineView" NSLog, also log routeLine.points and routeLine.pointCount.  If you create the same polyline from FirstViewController itself without going to child, does it work?